# how can I program the volume serial number into a variable for a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This Win7 batch file code retrieves the Serial Numbers for all drives on the computer and displays them in a command window, however
I am unable to isolate just the drive `%~d0` from which the code is running and capture the `volumeserialnumber` into a `%variable_%`.

```
rem -----------Test volumeSerialNumber.BAT------------------

@echo off
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get volumeserialnumber
pause

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ("wmic logicaldisk where deviceid = '%~d0' get volumeserialnumber") do (
  set SERIAL=%%j
  goto :DONE
)
:DONE
echo  SERIAL=%SERIAL%
echo %SERIAL%
pause

if "%SERIAL%"=="The Serial Number of Drive C" (
   echo "Success!"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just needed to change some single and double quotes.

Try:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%j In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%~d0'" Get VolumeSerialNumber') Do ...
```